# firebase save child object is stored as '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm learning Firebase and Angular4 and am using AngularFire2.

I have a list of items with a custom key and I have a list of owners, also with a custom key in a firebase db.

I first joined the item with his owner by using its key in the item and when retrieving the item I would do a second request to get the data of the owner.

I understand that this is not the way to handle this in a NoSQL database, it is better to save the whole owner object as a child in my item. Then I would not need to get the owner detail separately.

I have a form to edit the item data, which has a select box with all the owners. This list of owners is retrieved in ngOnInit. The selectbox is populated as:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="owner" id="owner">
  <option *ngFor="let ownerList of owners" [value]="ownerList">
    {{ownerList.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure if I create this select box correctly, but it seems to be working.

OnSubmit I do:

```
updateItem(alias: string, formValues: Item) {
  const mergedUpdate = {};
  mergedUpdate[ "item/" + alias] = formValues;
  this.af.database.ref().update(mergedUpdate);
}
```

When I now look at how the data is saved in the firebase console I see for owner `[object Object]`

I've been reading numerous posts but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Please advice.

Comment: What is `Item`? Maybe you need to parse to plain JSON before saving.

Comment: `Item` is an object. What's the problem?

Comment: You are not making object in correct way. as @MarianoCórdoba mentioned prepare a JSON object  e.r `{'property1':'value1',..................}`

Comment: I found the problem using https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2. I need to use `ngValue` instead of `value`. Now it is working as expected. If one of you post this, I'll mark it as an answer.